# LINQ, select one item from one table, multiple items from another table

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am fairly new to using LINQ and are now trying to build a LINQ question I do not quite manage to solve.
I would like to ask a question to a database, where I want to bring back single rows from a few tables, but a list of rows from other tables.

See code below too see what I am trying to do:

```
public DB.store store { get; set; }
public List<DB.gallery_image> images { get; set; }
public List<DB.product> products { get; set; }

public static List<Store> getStoreInfo()
{
    DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();

    var _dataToGet = from _store in db.stores
                     select new Store
                     {
                         store = _store,
                         images = (from a in db.gallery_images
                                    where a.albumID == _store.storeID
                                    select a).ToList(),
                         products = (from p in db.products
                                    where p.storeID = _store.storeID).ToList()
                     };

    return _dataToGet.ToList();
}
```

So I just want one row from "store" table, but a list from "images" and "product" tables.
The code above works fine, but is slow as hell.
I don't have any problems to select data from multiple tables as long as there is only one (or none) row per table, but when it is a list I'm having problem...

Comment: To start with, this is wrong "where a.albumID == _store.storeID"

Comment: Depending on you solution you might be able to write "images = _store.Images.ToList()" and "products = _store.Products.ToList()". Do you get the desired result if you split it up so you first get all stores, then loop through them and setting images and products. (also write .ToList()) when gettings stores.

Comment: If you're just selecting the same type you already have you might just write "return db.stores.Include(s => s.Images)... .ToList();"

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use deferred execution rather than materializing the queries with a call to `ToList`. I would change the data type of `images` and `products` to `IEnumerable<>` instead of `List<>`. Then I would not call `ToList` in the sub-queries because this results in a roundtrip to the database, hence, depending on how many `stores` you have it could turn into an extremely slow query.

You should see a performance gain here...

```
public DB.store store { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<DB.gallery_image> images { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<DB.product> products { get; set; }

public static List<Store> getStoreInfo()
{
    DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();

    var _dataToGet = from _store in db.stores
                     select new Store
                     {
                         store = _store,
                         images = (from a in db.gallery_images
                                    where a.albumID == _store.storeID
                                    select a),
                         products = (from p in db.products
                                    where p.storeID = _store.storeID)
                     };

    return _dataToGet.ToList();
}
```